# Trying to avoid duplicates when creating new array from comparing value of two others

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an app where I need to create a new array by pushing values from two other arrays after comparing what values in one array exist in another.

Example:
From these two arrays...

```
sel[1,4];

bus[1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

The desired result is a new object array which will populate a repeater of checkboxes in my view...

```
newList[{1:true},{2:false},{3:false},{4:true},{5:false},{6:false}];
```

The problem I'm running into, is that my code is creating duplicates and I'm not seeing why.

Here is my code:

```
  var newList = [];
  var bus = self.businesses;
  var sel = self.campaign.data.businesses;



  for( var b = 0; b < bus.length; b++ ){
    if(sel.length > -1){
      for( var s = 0; s < sel.length; s++){
          if( bus[b]._id === sel[s].business_id){
            newList.push({'business_id':bus[b]._id, 'name':bus[b].business_name, 'selected':true});
          } else {
            newList.push({'business_id':bus[b]._id, 'name':bus[b].business_name, 'selected':false});
          }
      }
    } else {
      console.log('hit else statement');
      newList.push({'business_id':bus[b]._id, 'name':bus[b].business_name, 'selected':false});
    }
  }
```

I need fresh eyes on this as it looks correct to me... but obviously I'm missing something. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code produces duplicates because you push `selected: false` objects into your `newList` every time the inner loop is run and the ids don't match:

```
for( var s = 0; s < sel.length; s++){
    if( bus[b]._id === sel[s].business_id){
        newList.push({'business_id':bus[b]._id, 'name':bus[b].business_name, 'selected':true});
    } else {
        // THIS LINE CAUSES THE DUPLICATES:
        newList.push({'business_id':bus[b]._id, 'name':bus[b].business_name, 'selected':false});
    }
}
```

To fix your code, move this line out of the inner loop into the outer loop below and add a `continue outer;` to the inner loop's `if` body. Then you need to place the `outer` label directly in front of the outer loop: `outer: for( var b = 0; b < bus.length; b++ ) ...`.

However, I recommend a simpler implementation as follows:

```js
let selection = [{_id: 1, business_name: 'A'}];
let businesses = [{_id: 1, business_name: 'A'}, {_id: 2, business_name: 'B'}];

let result = businesses.map(business => ({
   'business_id': business._id,
   'name': business.business_name,
   'selected': selection.some(selected => business._id == selected._id)
}));

console.log(result);
```

Appendix: Same implementation with traditional functions:

```js
var selection = [{_id: 1, business_name: 'A'}];
var businesses = [{_id: 1, business_name: 'A'}, {_id: 2, business_name: 'B'}];

var result = businesses.map(function(business) {
  return {
    'business_id': business._id,
    'name': business.business_name,
    'selected': selection.some(function(selected) { return business._id == selected._id })
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: le_m, I like how clean your implimentation looks. Is that TypeScript?

Comment: @cnak2 It is JavaScript. The arrow functions `(args) => ...` have been introduced with the recent ECMA2015 (ES6) specifications and might have been inspired by TypeScript...

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm getting an unexpected token error on the fat arrow, which is why I asked. Running "jscs:all" (jscs) task
parseError: Unexpected token => at app/scripts/controllers/mycampaign.js :
    75 |      let businesses = self.campaign.data.businesses;
    76 |
    77 |      let result = businesses.map(business => ({
----------------------------------------------------^
    78 |         'business_id': business._id,
    79 |         'name': business.business_name,
>> 1 code style errors found!
Warning: Task "jscs:all" failed. Used --force, continuing.

Comment: @cnak2 It's probably caused by an outdated jscs - see also https://medium.com/@markelog/jscs-end-of-the-line-bc9bf0b3fdb2 - I added a variant using traditional functions in place of arrow functions, see updated answer

Comment: Thanks! It appears the "let" key word also causes the error in my particular config.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a different approach by using an object for `sel` and the just iterate `bus` for the new array with the values.

```js
function getArray(items, selected) {
    var hash = Object.create(null);
    selected.forEach(function (a) {
        hash[a] = true;
    });
    return items.map(function (a) {
        var temp = {};
        temp[a] = hash[a] || false;
        return temp;
    });
}

console.log(getArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 4]));
```

ES6 with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
function getArray(items, selected) {
    return items.map((s => a => ({ [a]: s.has(a) }))(new Set(selected)));
}

console.log(getArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` method on bus array and check if current value exists in sel array using `includes()`.

```js
var sel = [1,4];
var bus = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

var result = bus.map(e => ({[e] : sel.includes(e)}))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This combines both Nina Scholz elegant ES6 approach with le_m's more specific solution to give you something that is shorter, versatile, and repurposable.

```js
function getArray(items, selected, [...id] = selected.map(selector => selector._id)) {
  return [items.map((s => a => ({
    [a._id + a.business_name]: s.has(a._id)
  }))(new Set(id)))];
}

console.log(...getArray([{
  _id: 1,
  business_name: 'A'
}, {
  _id: 2,
  business_name: 'B'
}, {
  _id: 3,
  business_name: 'C'
}, {
  _id: 4,
  business_name: 'D'
}, {
  _id: 5,
  business_name: 'E'
}, {
  _id: 6,
  business_name: 'F'
}], [{
  _id: 1,
  business_name: 'A'
}, {
  _id: 2,
  business_name: 'B'
}]));
```